# mac os x 10.6: syslog() EXC_BAD_ACCESS

Tags: c, macos, gdb, stack-overflow

```
Program received signal EXC_BAD_ACCESS, Could not access memory.
Reason: KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS at address: 0x18d1c070
0x96350250 in strlen ()
(gdb) bt
#0  0x96350250 in strlen ()
#1  0x963574d1 in strdup ()
#2  0x9636e420 in asl_set_query ()
#3  0x9636e2d9 in asl_set ()
#4  0x9636d5d2 in vsyslog ()
#5  0x9636d3e1 in syslog ()
#6  0x23405e78 in gp_log (level=4, fmt=0x23429b68 "%-s:%4d: size: %d\n") at ../../rpc/mac/gp_lib.c:49
#7  0x23404c61 in rpc_encap (out=0xbfffb23c, args=0xbfffd2d0) at ../../rpc/rpc.c:178
#8  0x23405269 in rpc_encap_args (pkt_out=0xbfffb20c, pd=0x2342e460, args=0xbfffd2d0) at ../../rpc/rpc.c:120
#9  0x23405549 in rpc_call_common (c=0x23053048, pd=0x2342e460, args=0xbfffd2d0, timeout=0, pkt_in=0xbfffd30c, size_in=0xbfffd308) at ../../rpc/rpc.c:227
#10 0x234057f9 in rpc_call_actor (pd=0x2342e460, args=0xbfffd2d0, timeout=0, pkt_in=0xbfffd30c, size_in=0xbfffd308) at ../../rpc/rpc.c:204
#11 0x23402839 in MobileIPAPIStopRoaming_w () at ../../MIPSDKv4/MobileIPSDK/MobileIP4_w.c:229
#12 0x23401420 in MobileIPAPIStopRoaming (mipHandle=1) at ../../MIPSDKv3/MobileIPSDKv3.c:300
#13 0x21c0e1a6 in GP_ICM_CONNMGR::CMobileIpSdk::MobileIPAPIStopRoaming ()
#14 0x21c0e6cf in GP_ICM_CONNMGR::CMobileIpSdk::Uninit ()
#15 0x1e749c19 in GP_ICM_RULEMGR::CRulesManager::Uninit ()
#16 0x0004df18 in CConnectionManager::UninitConnectionManager ()
#17 0x0013e6b4 in ICMApplication::UninitICMApplication ()
#18 0x001495b2 in main ()
(gdb) info registers 
eax            0xffffffff   -1
ecx            0x18d1c07c   416399484
edx            0x18d1c070   416399472
ebx            0x9636e2f0   -1774787856
esp            0xbfffaa4c   0xbfffaa4c
ebp            0xbfffaa78   0xbfffaa78
esi            0x964c6cc0   -1773376320
edi            0x18d1c07c   416399484
eip            0x96350250   0x96350250 <strlen+16>
eflags         0x10286  66182
cs             0x17 23
ss             0x1f 31
ds             0x1f 31
es             0x1f 31
fs             0x0  0
gs             0x37 55
(gdb) frame 1
#1  0x963574d1 in strdup ()
(gdb) frame 2
#2  0x9636e420 in asl_set_query ()
(gdb) frame 3
#3  0x9636e2d9 in asl_set ()
(gdb) frame 4
#4  0x9636d5d2 in vsyslog ()
(gdb) frame 5
#5  0x9636d3e1 in syslog ()
(gdb) frame 6
#6  0x23405e78 in gp_log (level=4, fmt=0x23429b68 "%-s:%4d: size: %d\n") at ../../rpc/mac/gp_lib.c:49
49      syslog(5, "%s", buf);
(gdb) p buf
$5 = "rpc_encap: 178: size: 48\n", '\0' <repeats 998 times>
(gdb) p level
$6 = 4
(gdb) p fmt
$7 = 0x23429b68 "%-s:%4d: size: %d\n"
```

The gp_log function is this:

```
#define LOG_DEBUG(format, ...) gp_log(DL_DEBUG, "%-s:%4d: " format, __FUNCTION__, __LINE__, ##__VA_ARGS__)

#define LOG_MAX_LENGTH      1024

void gp_log(int level, const char *fmt, ...)
{
    va_list ap;
    char buf[LOG_MAX_LENGTH] = {0};

    if (level > log_level)
        return;

    va_start(ap, fmt);
    vsnprintf(buf, LOG_MAX_LENGTH, fmt, ap);
    va_end(ap);

    syslog(level, "%s", buf);
    //printf("%s", buf);
}
```

This statement in rpc_encap print out the contents of an integer, which lead to this crash.

```
LOG_DEBUG("size: %d\n", size);
```

The crash is 100% reproduceable. I examine the parameters to syslog() every time before
crash:
buf is always "rpc_encap: 178: size: 48\n".
level is always 4.

If I use printf instead of syslog, the crash disappeared.

Comment: Excuse me but what does `%-s` mean?

Comment: %-s means print a string to be left adjusted on the field boundary

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#technotes/tn2004/tn2123.html : "This is caused by the thread accessing unmapped memory. It may be triggered by either a data access or an instruction fetch; the Thread State section describes how to tell the difference."

Answer (score 0):

In order to build a universal library for Mac 10.5/6/7(Intel arch), I add these flags when compiling on 10.6 or 10.7,

```
CFLAGS = -force_cpusubtype_ALL -mmacosx-version-min=10.5 -arch i386
```

and crash happened.

Now I remove these flags and build on 10.5, no more crash(also the library works on 10.5/6/7).